# XSLT 1.0 skip node attribute from the list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have variable that has many Node values.

`<xsl:variable name="IgnoreItems" select="'ITEM10 | ITEM20 | ITEM30| ITEM50'......| ITEMX'" />`

I would like to ignore those values when executing the For-each loop.

`<xsl:for-each select ="//Instruction/Item[@Definition !=$IgnoreItems]/Deviations/Planned">`

How this can be achieved using XSL 1.0 ?

Comment: The syntax of your sample is not clear `'ITEM10 | ITEM20 | ITEM30| ITEM50'......| ITEMX`, seems to have a closing single quote `'` in the middle of the data. As for XSLT 1, which processor, any extension easily available to tokenize such a string on `|` or ` | `? Also, how does the data exactly look, is `Definition="Item10"` or `Definition="Item10 "`? In any way, one trick is the check e.g. `contains(concat('|', $IgnoreItems, '|'), concat('|', @Definition, '|'))`.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have corrected the single quote typo error in the question,, "|" is just a separator. I couldn't use Definition="Item10"` or Definition="Item10 " option because need to ignore more than 50 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick is to check e.g. `Item[not(contains(concat('| ', $IgnoreItems, ' |'), concat('| ', @Definition, ' |')))]`. Or check whether the processor has or allows an easy `tokenize` extension so that you can use `Item[not(@Definition = ext:tokenize($IgnoreItems, ' \| '))]` or similar depending on whether the extension functions works with substrings or regular expression patterns.